# continuity in an interval

Tags: functions, limits, continuity

Suppose $f$ is a function as $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ and continuous on $[0,1]$.
How can I prove that  $\exists x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)= x_0$.
Also, how can I prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb {N} \ast  \exists a_n \in [0,1] such that {a}*{n} = {a}*{n}^{n}.

Comment: I don't understand what the second part means, please edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: I edited the question, but which part isn't clear me too I can't prove that.

Comment: The set $\mathbb{N}^*$ should be the positive integers?

Comment: I think so. n>0 / n \in \mathbb {N}

Comment: Then you can let $a_n=1$ for all $n>1$. Since $1^n=1$ for all $n$, this works.

Answer (score 2):

Show that the function $x\mapsto f(x)-x$ is continuous too, is nonpositve at one point, nonegative at one point and therefore zero at some point by the intermediate value theorem.