# Let $\displaystyle f$ be a continuous function from $[0,4]$ to $[3,9].$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I came across the following problem that says:

> Let $\displaystyle f$ be a continuous function from $[0,4]$ to $[3,9].$ The which of the following options is correct?
>   $1.$ there must be an $x$ such that $f(x)=4$
>   $2.$ there must be an $x$ such that $3f(x)=2x+6$
>   $3.$ there must be an $x$ such that $2f(x)=3x+6$
>   $4.$ there must be an $x$ such that $f(x)=x$  .

I do not know how to progress with it.Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

**EDIT:** Using the hint given by @Sampath ,I see that

Since "A continuous function $f:[a,b] \to [c,d]$ must intersect the line joining $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$", so here the line joining the  points $(0,3)$ and $(4,9)$ is given by $y=f(x)=\frac {3x+6}{2} \implies 2f(x)=3x+6.$

Comment: Can you really not exclude *any* of the options? Some of them are pretty obviously wrong.

Comment: Try drawing a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** A continuous function $f:[a,b] \to [c,d]$ must intersect the line joining joining $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
For the "no" answers, give a counter example. For the "yes" answers, apply the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try constant functions, as they behave the most easiest.

Use that $4 \leq f(x) \leq 9$ and use the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 2):

First, we prove that if $f:[a,b]\to[a,b]$ is a continous function then there's a fixed point i.e. $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=x$. Indeed, let the function $h$ defined by $h(x)=f(x)-x$, then $h$ is continous on $[a,b]$ and $h(a)h(b)\leq0$ so by mean value theorem, there's $x\in[a,b]$ such that $h(x)=0$.

Now, we return to the question. In 3. we define the function $h$ by $h(x)=\frac{2f(x)-6}{3}$, so $h:[0,4]\to [0,4]$ is continous. We can conclude.

Answer (score 1):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211242/fixed-point-in-a-continuous-function). Here is a useful result

" Every continuous function $f$ from a convex compact subset $K$ of a Euclidean space to $K$ itself has a fixed point".

The above result is known as [Brouwer fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: If the OP know how to use that result, he wouldn't ask this question

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: The tag is real analysis and it is a useful result. Thanks for the comment.