# Let $f$ be a continuous map then which of the following is correct

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function from $[0,4]$ to $[3,6]$ Then

(a) There must be a $x$ such that $f(x) = 4$

(b) There must be a $x$ such that $3f(x) = 2x+6$

(c)There must be a $x$ such that  $2f(x) = 2x+6$

(d)There must be a $x$ such that  $f(x) = x$

Using Intermediate Value theorem I know that (a) must be correct ,   but I have no idea for rest of the options  any hints will be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you missing a hypothesis? Is the function supposed to be surjective?

Comment: (a) must not be correct, consider $f(x) = 3$. This shows you can't use the IVT as you did.

Comment: No ,nothing about surjectivity is mentioned in the question .We have to consider a general function here.

Comment: @sat091 without surjectivity, the conditions of the IVP are not satisfied so a) doesn‘t have to be true

Comment: this question is remarkably similar to the top related link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322756/let-displaystyle-f-be-a-continuous-function-from-0-4-to-3-9?rq=1

Comment: @CalvinKhor this question came in my test a few days back . I guess our teacher used https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322756/let-displaystyle-f-be-a-continuous-function-from-0-4-to-3-9?rq=1  to create the given problem

Answer (score 2):

Visual aid as hint - can you draw a graph in the shaded region starting from $x=0$ ending at $x=4$ that doesn't 
 intersect (a) the blue line? (b) the green line? (c) yellow line? (d) black line?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is (c).

Let $g(x)=2f(x)-2x-6$.

Then $g(0)=2f(0)-6\ge2(3)-6=0$ and $g(4)=2f(4)-14\le 2(6)-14<0$.

By IVT, there must be a $x$ such that $g(x)=0$.

For other options, we can find a $f(x)$ to avoid equality. (See Calvin Khor's answer)