# How to check for fixed points

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

How to check for fixed points in such type of questions

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. If $f$ has two distinct fixed points $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $[a,b]$, then by the Mean Value Theorem, there is $t\in (a,b)$ such that
$$x_1-x_2=f(x_1)-f(x_2)=f'(t)(x_1-x_2).$$

Moreover see [Proof for the property of a fixed point of $f$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549753/proof-for-the-property-of-a-fixed-point-of-f)